# jQuery .submit() - No Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am Unable to submit a form using jQuery `.submit()` function. On my website, I have:

1. index.php
2. view-detail.php
3. form-process.php

On `index.php` page, is a list of records that user can click to view full details of the records.

The `view-detail.php` page show the record details and also a form if user want to update the status approval.

`form-process.php` will be the form processing for update record

> **Codes**

**index.php**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
        function myForm(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'form-process.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("success");
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error Submitting');
                }
            })
        }

        $(".view_detail").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            url = $(this).attr('href');

            $.get(url, function(data){
                $("#section").html(data);
                $("form").submit(myForm);    
            });
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="section"> 
   <!-- records from db and link to view full detail -->
   <a href="view-detail.php?id='.$permohonan_id.'" class="view_detail">View</a>
</div>
```

**view-detail.php**

```
<form id="myForm" name="kelulusan" action="<?php echo 'form-process.php'; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="sokongan">
        <input type="radio" name="kelulusan" id="dp" value="Dalam Proses"> Dalam Proses<br>
        <input type="radio" name="kelulusan" id="ll" value="Lulus"> Lulus<br>
        <input type="radio" name="kelulusan" id="tl" value="Tidak Lulus"> Tidak Lulus 
    </div>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="pid"  value="<?php echo $pid;?>"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

**form-process.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['kelulusan'])){
    $status = $_POST['kelulusan'];
    echo "Update : $status ";
}
// validate and update database query
?>
```

When I click on the submit button, there is response from the form. May I know why and how to resolve it?

Comment: You need to bind an event listener to your form. `$('#myform').on('click', myForm);`

Comment: @mkaatman event is submit right? @Amran why do you have `e.preventDefault();` in your function can you remove it

Comment: @mkaatman for the on click event, do I need to insert on the `.get()` success function

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to `submit` the form using the "normal" form behavior, you better use a button.
It can be as simple as this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myForm();">
```

Or you can use an `event` handler and an `id` like this:

```
<input type="button" id="SubmitTheForm">

$("#SubmitTheForm").on("click",function(){
  myForm();
});
```

Then, It is true that `preventDefault()` will be useless.
It is, if you use a `submit` button.